# Resolution algorithm does not seem to generate the empty clause

Tags: logic, satisfiability, artificial-intelligence, first-order-logic

Let's assume I have the following 3 clauses:
$\neg T$,$\neg Q$, ($\neg P \lor Q \lor S \lor T)$,$(\neg U, T, \neg S)$,$(\neg U, T, P)$

and I want to see if our KB entails $\neg U$ so I tried to apply the resolution algorithm like below:

$$
(\neg P \lor Q \lor S \lor T) \land \neg T \land \neg Q \land (\neg U \lor T \lor \neg S) \land (\neg U \lor T \lor P) \land U
$$
By applying the algorithm on the first two clauses we'll have:
$$
(\neg P \lor Q \lor S) \land (\neg Q) \land (\neg U \lor T \lor \neg S) \land (\neg U \lor T \lor P) \land U
$$
Again by applying the algorithm on the first two clauses we'll have:
$$
(\neg P \lor S) \land (\neg U \lor T \lor \neg S) \land (\neg U \lor T \lor P) \land U
$$
By applying full resolution on the first two clauses(for $S$) we'll have:
$$
(\neg P \lor \neg U \lor T) \land (\neg U \lor T \lor P) \land U\\
\rightarrow (\neg U \lor T) \land U\\
\rightarrow T
$$
I don't know where to go from here. Obviously, our knowledge base entails $\neg U$ and the resolution algorithm is supposed to be complete, but I don't know which step in my solution is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simpler example. The clauses $A \lor B$, $\lnot A$, $A$ are clearly contradictory. Applying resolution, we resolve the first two clauses, and are left with the two clauses $B$ and $A$. Now we are stuck.

Your issue is similar. When applying the Resolution rule, we don't remove the resolved clauses. Rather, we retain them. The completeness of Resolution states that if the original clauses are unsatisfiable, then there is a way to repeatedly apply the Resolution rule, *not removing the resolvents*, that will eventually produce the empty clause. In fact, the following rule will work:

> Repeat until no longer possible: resolve a pair of clauses which produce a clause not already present.

Comment: I still don't get it. Are we supposed to do it in an order?

Comment: Spend more time thinking about it.

Comment: By the way, in Resolution we don't *replace* resolved clauses with their resolvent. Rather, we *add* the resolved clause to the list of known clauses.

Comment: Oh, so I can still resolve T with its negated literal to get an empty clause. Correct me if I'm wrong but even in your example, it is enough to create the empty clause by applying resolution on A and its negation.

Comment: Right, you can resolve $T$ with $\lnot T$ to find the empty clause.